# Installing non HP drives into an ML350 G6

Tags: hardware

Basically, complete n00b here when it comes to servers.

I'm looking to purchase an ml350 G6 and install some regular sata hard drives into it - is this possible? I would obviously buy the LFF version with the 6 x 3.5" hot swap bays.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: HP will not support **any** problems related to the disks if you install these. Just fair warning.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping]http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Although the disks themselves would almost certainly work (the controller might complain due to them not running the custom HP firmware) the issue is that the HP original disks come in their proprietry physical caddy - which you can't buy on their own of course - so you couldn't plug them in sorry.

Comment: You can buy the caddies for about $25 each. And 99% of SATA drives will work; but with degraded performance, less reporting, and likely a shorter lifetime.

Comment: Really? have you got a HP part number to hand at all?

Comment: LFF Trays are 373211-001; SFF 378343-002; SATA and SAS both use the same tray. I haven't found a part number for the MSA2 Trays yet, they're different and have an adapter board on the back.

Answer (score 1):

So this is possible, trust me I have 6 servers this way.

for LFF drives- http://discountechnology.com/Compaq-SATA-SAS-Hard-Drive-Tray-Caddy-CPN373211-001

for SFF drives- "http://discountechnology.com/HP-Compaq-378343-002-SATA-SAS-Hard-Drive-Tray-Caddy"

Any sata drive will do.. (I like WD black myself.)

Comment: There are consequence to putting consumer grade drives in servers; you should fully understand the consequences before doing this. There are good reasons professions (who know most SATA drives work) still buy the HP drives.

Comment: Good reason #1:  "Somebody else is paying for them."